# Unable to post to a database MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am attempting to post a column into my database here as a test and I am unable to do so. I've used the code below and it doesn't seem to be posting. Unless I am missing a trick with PHPmyAdmin I cannot seem to get it working. Any chance anyone could help? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php 

   $link = mysqli_connect("XXXX", "XXXX", 
   "XXXX", "XXXX");

   if (mysqli_connect_error ()) {

     die("The connection has failed");

   }

   $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) 
   VALUES('owen@owen.com', 'hfudhf8ahdfufh')";

   mysqli_query($link, $query);

   $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
   if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     echo"Your Email is ".$row["email"];
     echo" and your Password is ".$row["password"];

   }

?>
```

Comment: your SELECT query will only be visible after you've reloaded it since you're inserting then immediately wanting to echo from the following query. In any case, use `mysqli_error($link)` on both queries, you may have a unique constraint

Comment: I hope those aren't actual login credentials. If so, you'd better go and change them right away.

Comment: well they sure looked real to me; Edit: and you deleted the comment I was replying to.

Comment: Use `mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));` to see if there's an error.

Comment: I thought you were talking about the Database insert credentials. It has since been removed by a lovely man Barmar. Stupid 2:30 am me. Thanks for the response I shall give it a go.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why won't it be visible until a reload? He's selecting after the insert, so it should get the new row if they were added.

Comment: @Barmar I'm right on this. Btw, you made a typo `mysqli_error($line)`.

Comment: @Thanks, I made that typo twice in the comment. But I still don't understand your point about not seeing the new row when he does the select. It's not like they're in different transactions.

Comment: No errors are showing on the page

Comment: There we go, I've fixed it, I refreshed the page and entered new random values for the insert. Thanks for the help guys and thanks @Barmar for the edit there

Comment: @Barmar My *duh*, sorry about that. Well in either case and as I told Owen; he has to check for errors. If none are thrown then maybe he's using `file:///` as opposed to `http://localhost`. I don't know, I'm not sitting beside him ;-) only he knows what's going on over there and what he's doing. He says no errors are thrown; I don't see error checking here. Maybe his column lengths are too short and failing silently; no idea.

Comment: You need to change the code after the `SELECT` so it fetches all the results in a loop.

Comment: *"I refreshed the page and entered new random values for the insert"* - which tells me that you have a constraint somewhere and it didn't let you enter the same values twice; least that's what I make of this.

Comment: Yes sorry a bit vague. It may have been an internet issue. Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're only fetching one row of results. Unless the table was empty before you ran the script, there's no reason to expect that row to be the one that you just added.

If the table has an auto-increment ID field, you can fetch that row:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()";
```